# Italics don't work in Careers cover letter editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I recently submitted a job application on Careers, and I wanted to make use of the "italic text" feature that was built in to the cover letter edit box.

It seemed to work well while I was editing the cover letter, however when I went back to make a change later (and during the review step), the italics had disappeared and the spacing around the italicized words was gone.

Also, I tried using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> instead of the icon, and while the mode toggling worked, when I left italic mode the italicized word I had just written became un-italicized (this was in the editor, before preview mode). The spacing remained normal. Not sure if this is a bug or misfeature. This is independent from the bug outlined in the above paragraph.

I am using Google Chrome (latest as of question posting).

Comment: What version of Chrome? (as in `25.0.1364.172 (Official Build 187217) m`)

Comment: @Doorknob: Ah, sorry, should have been more specific. Yes, `25.0.1364.172 (Official Build 187217) m` (from chrome://version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this and it's on it's way out now.